# What is the difference between capacitative and inductive coupling in a twisted pair?

Tags: inductive, twisted-pair

I'm learning about networking and there is this passage:
"Twisting cancels out inductive coupling, while the shield eliminates capacitive coupling."
What kind of effects are these, qualitatively speaking? For example, if I have two wires which aren't twisted around each other, how would they affect each other? Or if I have two twisted pairs, which aren't shielded from each other, how would they affect each other?

Comment: not `each other` ... coupling that is external to the twisted pair

Comment: Not ‘capacitative’

Comment: You just want to condense volumes of Henry Ott’s book to 1 page?     Go read the book or similar https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C140914/talks/tutub1_talk.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faraday’s law of induction describes the effect of inductive coupling. A transformer is an example of this in action. This is electromagnetic or inductive coupling.

This is the reason why you avoid running networking ( or other comms) cables in parallel with mains wiring - the high currents in the mains wiring can induce voltages onto the network wiring. Bad juju. The twisting provides a degree of protection but it is not perfect, so keep network wiring away from mains.

Two conductors separated by an insulator (dielectric) form a capacitor. A fast changing voltage on one conductor can be coupled into the other. This is referred to as electrostatic or capacitive coupling.
In network cables you can have a shield whose job is to be the other conductor in a capacitor rather than the wires with the network signals. There is a drain wire that connects to the shield which is earthed in order to ‘drain’ the electrostatic charge.
One source of electrostatic charges is humans accumulating a charge by triboelectric effects.  This dan be transferred by touching the network cable.
The main source is RF signals from cell phones and other sources of radio transmission.

Nearby lightning strikes can induce both electrostatic and electromagnetic interference.